# Android Facebook Login and LinkedIn Login in the same activity

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, linkedin-api

I have login with facebook (Custom button not with LoginButton) and login with LinkedIn in the same Activity so how to handle this in onActivityResult of my Activity ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Put a flag when button is clicked .If you are pressing facebook button than put that variable true .After processing make that variable false.

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (btnFacebook)
    {
        // handle fb events
        btnFacebook=false;
    }
    else
    {
        // handle instagram events
        btnInsta=false;
    }

}
```